Find My Device - Is 2FA No Longer Required?
I've done a bit of experimentation which is related to this question.
2FA has been active on accounts, however, Find My Device seems to no longer require the second factor - only password is required. This seems to be the case when using an authenticator app, as well as the case of using a phone as a passkey. I also tested using a VPN to make my desktop IP one in another country.
Can anyone confirm this or have an canonical links to this change by Google?
I guess this makes sense in the case of a lost device where you need to log into a fresh device in order to locate it, and your device was the second factor.
However, on the negative side any threat actor with your password only can locate your device and lock or reset it, albeit with a notification sent to you first.

Reading Google Account Help - Turn on 2-Step Verification, I think Google has its own priority of which 2FA is requested based on convenience, or you probably checked "Don't ask again" before.

From my testing from clean browsers (i.e. no cookies or local storage retained), no 2FA method was requested. I believe the "Don't ask again" applies only to the current browser, not to the account.

I think... it's per device, but I don't have any proof either.

Browsers don't have any concept of device - if you clear cookies, local storage, etc, then the device is new as far as Google login is concerned. Interesting if you get the 2FA prompt for you? I've tested with a bunch of accounts, some Workspace, some Gmail and also over VPN with a fresh browser. Each time all I need is the main account password to login.
